# Moment js. How to convert the current time to a different time zone

Tags: javascript, web, frontend

For example current time (Timezone +2) time 11:00 how to get this time for (Time zone +9). Need to use *moment js*.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is explained in momentjs documentation

https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/

Their example:

```
var m = moment.tz("2013-11-18 11:55", "America/Toronto");
m.format();                     // 2013-11-18T11:55:00-05:00
m.startOf("day").format();      // 2013-11-18T00:00:00-05:00
m.tz("Europe/Berlin").format(); // 2013-11-18T06:00:00+01:00
m.startOf("day").format();      // 2013-11-18T00:00:00+01:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `moment().utcOffset(9);` and with a given date just do `moment(givenDate).utcOffset(9);`

Please see [momentjs.com/docs/](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc-offset/)